# Can I use gazebo 3.0 with ros-hydro on Ubuntu Trusty 14.04

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have red Gazebo is a standalone application. Does Hydro support Gazebo 3.0 ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191554/can-i-use-gazebo-3.0-with-ros-hydro-on-ubuntu-trusty-14.04/) by [tonyParker](https://answers.ros.org/users/15131/tonyparker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 377 on 2014-08-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, this is not supported in the official builds of ROS.

ROS Hydro supports Gazebo 1.9 on Ubuntu 12.04, 12.10 and 13.04

ROS Indigo supports Gazebo 2.0 on Ubuntu 13.10 and 14.04

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1